# Run JS Function on Page Load Complete // Firefox Extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm working on a Firefox extension that shows directly the amount of cookies on a website. I managed that the number of cookies is shown when the icon of the extension is clicked, but I already need to load the funtion when the page is loaded. How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `document.ready(function (){//your code})`?

Answer (score 0):

if you using Jquery than:

```
(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

More information

https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    //....
});
```

Comment: While your code may answer the PO's question, you should add a brief explanation of what you have done and how that solves the problem.